# Ubuntu 21.10: ZFS pool automount not working (updated to 21.10 last night)

Tags: zfs

setup: Ubuntu 21.10 (with latest updates). The problem happened even before 21.10 was out. I just never bothered fixing it until now.

zfs version is:

```
root@myserver:~# zfs --version
zfs-2.0.2-1ubuntu5.1
zfs-kmod-2.0.2-1ubuntu5.4
```

I found this in the logs:

```
root@myserver:~# journalctl -b | grep zfs
Jan 27 09:12:21 myserver udevadm[702]: systemd-udev-settle.service is deprecated. Please fix multipathd.service, zfs-import-cache.service, zfs-load-module.service not to pull it in.
Jan 27 09:12:22 myserver systemd[1]: zfs-import-cache.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 27 09:12:22 myserver systemd[1]: zfs-import-cache.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I then tried mounting my pool using the cache

```
root@myserver:~# ls -al /etc/zfs/zpool.cache
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4016 Jan 27 08:03 /etc/zfs/zpool.cache
root@myserver:~# zpool import -c /etc/zfs/zpool.cache -aN
cannot import 'storage-myserver': one or more devices is currently unavailable
```

but no issues importing the pool using this command

```
root@myserver:~# zpool import storage-myserver
```

I tried recreating the cache file using the command below but auto-import still doesn't work (after a reboot) and re-running the zpool import -c command above has no effect

```
# zpool set cachefile=/etc/zfs/zpool.cache storage-myserver
```

Any ideas on how to fix?
Thanks

Comment: Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades